# What does the name between [] printed using log interface of org.apache.commons.logging mean in a grails app?

Tags: multithreading, logging, grails

I am trying to debug a problem in a grails application and I see in log:
 `[http-nio-8180-exec-19] ERROR org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl  - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1]`. I want to know what http-nio-8180-exec-19 stands for and if I can use this thread name to track what user did the operation that lead to the exception.

Can I assume that on thread http-nio-8180-exec-19 I will see all the operations done by just an user and each user that will log into the application will have a different thread associated?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default I believe those are the names of threads, though you could put whatever you want there.  If you have something like `[%15.15t]`  in your `logback.groovy`, that is what is causing the thread name to be inserted there.